# replaced front brake pads but the pedal is still flooring

Tags: brakes

I replaced brakes on my gmas saturn, which ive done before without issues, but the pedal is still flooring. I noticed the fluid is just sittin in the container? Is it the master or could it.be somethjng else? Theres a lot of things I know this car hasnt had a lot of.work done and could use a lot.of fixing but how could I pinpoint exactly which one

Comment: Did you bleed the brakes?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you try pumping the brakes a few times? It can take a few strokes of the pedal to push the caliper pistons out enough where you'll start feeling some resistance. May take a few stabs.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the master cylinder.  However, check the brake booster, brake lines, grommets around the master cylinder as well just to make sure those aren't adding to things with small leaks.  If the fluid level stays at full, then replace the master cylinder.

By the way, does the pedal go slowly to the floor or quickly?

Answer (score 1):

Brake fluid is only good for 2-3 years, after which your system corrodes.  Steel cylinders have BIG problems with old DOT3/4 fluid.  If your pedal is going to the floor, the most likely problem is the master cylinder.  If you replace it yourself, be sure to bench bleed it before the install.  If you've done brake work and had the hydraulic system open, or if you tried to vacuum bleed it at the wheel, or if you released the pedal too rapidly while bleeding, you likely introduced air into the system.  I've found a gentle pressure bleed (3-5 psi on reservoir) with a check valve on the wheel bleeder works every time but not everyone has the equipment for this.